# Is there a way to prohibit the declarations of global variables in C/C++ when using GCC?

Tags: gcc

Say, if a project leader don't want his team members to use global variables, how can he do this technically? Is there an option when building GCC that makes it throw errors when it knows someone has declared a global variable?

And static global is allowed, however.

Comment: How do you plan to use `stdout` and `stderr` and `errno` if you can't declare global variables?  Do you really mean you don't want people to define global variables — though library implementers are exempted because they're required to defined `stdout` etc?

Comment: My suspicion is that you'd do best parsing the output of `nm -g file.o` (or thereabouts; the options can vary between systems, and the output formats vary dramatically between systems), looking for global variable definitions.  You could look for global variable references, but system libraries use them too, so you'd have to know which global variable references are OK and which are not.  I'm not aware of a GCC option for the job, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.  Have you looked at the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your reply. I was just saying that if there's an option. So using `nm` is of course a way to do it. Could you please answer that in the text box please?

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*As requested*</sup>

How do you plan to use `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` and `errno` (to name but four global variables) if you can't declare global variables? Do you really mean you don't want people to define global variables — though library implementers are exempted because they're required to defined `stdout` etc?

My suspicion is that you'd do best parsing the output of `nm -g file.o` (or thereabouts; the options can vary between systems, and the output formats vary dramatically between systems), looking for global variable definitions. You could look for global variable references, but system libraries use them too, so you'd have to know which global variable references are OK and which are not.

I'm not aware of a GCC option for the job, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Have you looked at the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)?  I did look and didn't find an appropriate warning — probably because it isn't a common requirement.